# Timing Issues with Layouting via didInsertElement view function

Tags: ember.js

I encounter ugly timing problems (race conditions) with putting code which carries out layout based on height calculations with jQuery in didInsertElement().
For example, I calculate the height of a header via `$('header.someClass').outerHeight(true);` then I use the result to offset the content area from the top. If I render the view completely new via reloading the whole page it works (60px in my example) but if I navigate to the view from another one, it fails because the wrong height is returned (6px in my example).
To prove that it is a timing issue: If I wrap the code in:

`Em.run.later(function() {
 ...do layout
}, 50);`

It works.
I consider this a serious issue because there are not other hooks in Ember, I can attach to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you should schedule your jQuery logic to run after the rendering:

```
App.YourView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement : function(){
    this._super();
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, function(){
        // perform your jQuery logic here
    });
  }
});
```

Find more infos and explanations in my [blog](http://mavilein.github.io/javascript/2013/08/01/Ember-JS-After-Render-Event/).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have a bit of a misunderstanding of how ember works.

didInsertElement is fired when that particular view is injected into the dom, not when all of the elements are in the dom.  Note: If the model behind it changes, ember won't fire didInsertElement again, because it wasn't reinserted into the dom.

If it works when you delay, then it sounds like your logic for calculating the size of something is depending on something that may not be there yet.

Feel free to show an example of it using emberjs.jsbin.com.